# PHP mongo aggregation: match multiple values on same field

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need the pipeline to match documents where field 'modelName' is equal to 'movies' or 'tv_shows'. I tried the code below but it matches only 'tv_shows' and ignores 'movies'.

```
$match = array('$match' => array('modelName' => 'movies', 'modelName' => 'tv_shows'));
```

Whole script:

```
<?php

   $connection = new MongoClient;
   $collection = $connection -> selectDB("getglue") -> selectCollection("gg");
   MongoCursor::$timeout = -1;

   $match = array('$match' => array('modelName' => 'movies', 'modelName' => 'tv_shows'));
   $group = array('$group' => array('_id' => '$title', 'total' => array('$sum' => 1)));
   $sort = array('$sort' => array('total' => -1));
   $limit = array('$limit' => 7);
   $pipeline = array($match, $group, $sort, $limit);

   $out = $collection -> aggregate($pipeline);

   echo json_encode($out, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `$or` operator:

```
$match = array('$match' => 
                 array('$or' => array(array("modelName" => "movies"),
                                array("modelName" => "tv_shows"))
                      )
     );
```

An `array` in PHP is actually an `ordered map`. A map can have only one value for any key, and the last added value will override any previous values for the same key. So, in the below, `tv_shows` which is the last added value for the key - `modelName` will be associated as the key's only value. And that is why you get the results only for `modelname` of `tv_shows`.

```
'$match' => array('modelName' => 'movies', 'modelName' => 'tv_shows')
```